# addthis preserving social sharing counters

Tags: javascript, php, addthis

I recently changed my website urls
The problem is that I no longer retrieves information from old pages

Is it possible to retrieve the information from the old urls? as the number of like Facebook for example ???

Here is the code I currently use (basic code)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-156104f8e532"></script>
```

and

```
<div class="addthis_native_toolbox"></div>
```

thx all for your help

Answer (score 1):

I am Elsa from AddThis support team.

We pull our sharing counts from different service providers we have to contend with how they count shares. Facebook, Twitter, and many others now consider even http and https URLs to be separate.

The best way to deal with this change on their end is to pick either the old URL or new URL and set it as your . This will cause all the AddThis tools to use the same URL regardless of which one the users came in on. You can then set your web server to redirect to one URL or the other when people click a shared link.

Thanks,
Elsa.

Comment: thx elsa, can you explain how i can do this please "to pick either the old URL or new URL and set it as your " thx

Comment: please help, i can't enable this function for the moment :)

Comment: I think she was talking about something like this: https://nrave.com/2016/10/lost-addthis-social-share-button-counts-after-moving-to-https/